# NotFoundHTTPException while pagination. Laravel

Tags: pagination, routes, laravel-5

I'm trying to paginate my views. I have used following syntax to do that:
Route:

```
Route::get('Bill/view/month/history','BillController@monthHistory');
```

Controller:

```
public function monthHistory(Request $request)
{
    $month= $request->month;
   $bills=Bill::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('month',$month)->paginate(7);
    $bills->setPath('custom/url');
return view('Bill.monthResult',compact('bills'));

}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @section ('cotable_panel_title','Bills')
        @section ('cotable_panel_body')
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Student</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Date Published</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Paid</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                    <th>User</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($bills as $bill)
                <tr class="info">
                    <td>{{$bill->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bill->student->first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bill->grade->grade_name}}</td>
                     <td>{{$bill->month}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bill->date_published}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bill->amount}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bill->paid}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bill->fee_status}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bill->user}}</td>



                </tr>

                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>    
        @endsection
        @include('widgets.panel', array('header'=>true, 'as'=>'cotable'))
    </div>
</div>
</div>


{!! $bills->render() !!}
```

While the Pagination works fine for the first page, When i click on next page it throws not foundhttpexception with URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/Bill/view/month/custom/url?page=2
```

How can i solve this problem? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you also need to have a GET route for

```
Route::get('Bill/view/month/history/custom/url','BillController@monthHistory');
```

in your routes file.

**or you can do this to**

use custom url as optional variables on your route as below.

```
Route::get('Bill/view/month/history/{custom?}/{url?}','BillController@monthHistory');
```

**and do use set path like this in your controller**

```
$bills->setPath('/Bill/view/month/history/custom/url');
```